# Draw $\frac{1}{z}$ in the complex plane

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis

Suppose you have a complex number $z$. How can you draw $\frac{1}{z}$ in the complex plane without calculations? I know $z\cdot \operatorname{conj}(z) = |z|^2$ so $\frac{1}{z} = \frac{\operatorname{conj}(z)}{|z|^2}$

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: Use $z=re^{i\theta}$

Comment: So, $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{r}e^{-i \theta}$ means that the angle is opposite, and the radius is the inverse multiplicative. How can I draw this radius?

Comment: On a number line, if I give you $n\neq 0$, can you pinpoint $\frac{1}{n}$?  There's no difference between that case and this.

Comment: No, that's my problem :(..

Comment: http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/CompassAndStraightedgeConstructionOfInversePoint.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just answered your own question.  Since $\frac{1}{z} = \overline{z}/|z|^2$, $\frac{1}{z}$ is the conjugate of $z$, reflected across the unit circle.  Alternately, as percusse suggested, if $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{r}e^{-i\theta}$.

This should work for sketching or giving you a sense of where $\frac{1}{z}$ lies given any (nonzero) $z$ unless you're looking for something more precise, like a compass-and-straightedge construction.  In that case, please make it clear in the question.